# Evaluation of the same expression differently in a combound condition

Tags: c#, if-statement, expression, conditional-statements

According to some sources dealing with condition coverage, a condition occuring more than once is counted once and the coverage requires 2^n test cases to test all combinations.
Well, what about this C# code?

```
if (A && B()) && (A || C)

bool A= true;

   bool B() {
    A=false; return true;}
```

A is evaluated to true in the first subexpression but changed to false during evaluation of B, so in the second expression A will be false. So it will have both true and false outcomes in an evaluation.
So how can one say that the condition is the same and thus counted as 1?

How to deal with that?

Comment: Is your question : "will this code requires 2^n test cases to test all combinations." ? Just want to clarify...

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you asking? Also, can you please clean up the formatting in your code and fix it so that it will actually compile?